# Trouble aligning boxes using flex in react

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox, jsx

I'm trying to get three blocks to be aligned like the red and the blue squares in what is shown here; http://jsfiddle.net/Manojkr/hqgx0ua8/. Currently all I can get is something that looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yxfks.jpg. I do no know what I am doing wrong. This is in react, but it shouldn't matter for what I am trying
to do. Or maybe it does? Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong, it appears that I am following the example very closely.

```
const FlexContainer = styled.div`
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
`


const DnDWrap = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0 auto;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
`

const EquipmentWrap = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: space-between;
`

const DnDContainer = styled.div`
  background-color: RGB(140, 133, 110);
  color: yellow;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
`

 <FlexContainer>
          <DnDWrap>
            <DnDContainer onClick={(e)=>this.changeCharacter(e)} style={styles.character}>
              Character
            </DnDContainer>
            <EquipmentWrap>
              <DnDContainer onClick={(e)=>this.changeEquipment(e)} style={styles.equipment}>
                  equipment
              </DnDContainer>
              <DnDContainer onClick={(e)=>this.changeEquipment(e)} style={styles.equipmentClearLeft}>
                  equipment
              </DnDContainer>
            </EquipmentWrap>
          </DnDWrap>
</FlexContainer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a general way using normal html/css that you can adapt. Create a main flex row with the left/right side, then a flex column for the blue boxes.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}
.grow {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.col {
  flex-direction: column;
}
.right {
  flex-basis: 48%;
}
.red {
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  margin-right: 1em;
}
.blue {
  background: blue;
}
.blue:first-child {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="grow red">
  </div>
  <div class="flex col right">
    <div class="grow blue"></div>
    <div class="grow blue"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```